# How to solve Manifest merger failed Error

Tags: android, build.gradle

I am building a familyGps tracker with firebase and I'm getting following error:

```
Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:9:5-31:19 to override.
```

My dependencies file include:

```
dependencies {

implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.8.+'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.2'
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.2.1"

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.1'
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.0'
}
```

Comment: Getting This Error:  
Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
 is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
 Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:9:5-31:19 to override.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because [android-image-cropper v2.8.0](https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper/releases/tag/2.8.0) is using androidX libraries implicitly which is clashed with the support libraries 28.0.0. You need to either downgrade android-image-cropper version to [2.7.0](https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper/releases/tag/2.7.0) or use androidX in your project.